# ueditor upload file size exceed carbon forum

Tags: php

ueditor upload file size exceed in carbon forum

carbon forum use ueditor as upload files, edit content.

I try to upload a 4MB pdf, but, it tells me file size exceeded.

How and where to config max upload file size limit?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do that, for those people who have same question.
Here is how:

open this file

C:\Apache24\htdocs\carbon-forum\library\Uploader.config.json

Edit this line:

"fileMaxSize": 2048000, /* 上传大小限制，单位B，默认2MB */

I set it to 50MB.

Now, still don't work, can't upload.

open file:
c:\php\php.ini

edite this line: default is 8M, I set it to 50M

post_max_size = 50M

upload_max_filesize = 50M (default is 2m)

Do not forget restart apache server to make php.ini effect